# Mod Rewrite ignore url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a site where instead of using GET variables I will just be looking at the url. How would you create a mod_rewrite rule that no matter what directs the user to index.php(Or some page)?

**EX:**
**User enters:** www.example.com/blog/programming/postName

User still sees www.example.com/blog/programming/postName in the adress bar but www.example.com/index.php is shown

**I have tried:**

```
RewriteRule    ^([a-z]+.)?$    /index.php    [NC,L]
```

But that only changes the page for one directory(only worked for www.example.com/worksNow/

```
RewriteRule    ^(.*)    /Blog3/index.php    [NC,L]
```

But It got a server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior/recipe doesn't require mod_rewrite, see FallBackResource.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Comment: Both using mod_rewrite and this method seem to behave exactly the same. Is there any reason using your method is better? I also ran into a problem were my files are not being found(such as an image) because the server thinks it is in a different directory when displaying an image or something like it. Is there anyway to make it so images are found besides adding a prefix to every single image?

Comment: It was added as an alternative to having to deal with the peculiaraties of mod_rewrite for a common/basic configuration.

Your logs will tell you exactly what resource the browser resolved your relative link to. You either need to fix what generates the links, or rewrite them to what exists on disk.  This is a normal consequence of hiding/adding context roots.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

This means if any request that is not for a file or directory then internally rewrite that to `/index.php`

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: That does work. However I do not know how that works. I understand this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]` but I do not know what the 2 lines above it do. Would you like to explain? I also ran into a problem were my files are not being found(such as an image) because the server thinks it is in a different directory when displaying an image or something like it. Is there anyway to make it so images are found besides adding a prefix to every single image?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means if request is not for a valid file and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means if request is not for a valid directory. Do check the mod_rewrite documentation link I have provided in my answer.